# Actualizar items automaticamente con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Necesito listar los elementos que contiene mi tabla "news" utilizo una petición ajax para traer los elementos

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../utilidades/backend/consulta_avisos_wa.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){                
        var data = JSON.parse(response);

        for (var i = 0; i <= data.length ; i++) {
            var elemento = document.createElement("div");
            elemento.classList.add('col-lg-4');
            elemento.innerHTML += ("<div class='card'>"
                + "<img class='card-img-top' src='../img/default-aviso.jpg' alt='cover card'>"
                + "<div class='card-body'>" + "<h5 class='card-title'>"+ data[i].titulo+"</h5>"
                + "<p class='card-text'>" + data[i].contenido + "</p>"
                );              
            document.getElementById('row-news').appendChild(elemento);
        }
    }
});
```

el archivo en donde ejecuto las consultas es el siguiente

```
$query = "SELECT n.title, n.registration_date,n.content,n.priority,n.new_id, concat(u.name,' ',u.last_name) as user_name, d.department_name from news n inner JOIN users u on n.user = u.user_id INNER JOIN department d on n.department = d.department_id";            
$result = $con_mysqli->query($query) or die (mysqli_errno($con_mysqli));
$filas = mysqli_affected_rows($con_mysqli); 
$response = [];

    while($fila = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        $new = [
            'id'        =>  $fila['new_id'],
            'titulo'    =>  $fila['title'],
            'fecha'     =>  $fila['registration_date'],
            'contenido' =>  $fila['content'],
            'prioridad' =>  $fila['priority'],
            'usuario'   =>  $fila['user_name'],
            'departamento'  =>  $fila['department_name']
        ];          
        array_push($response, $new);
    }
echo json_encode($response);
```

**No tengo ningún problema o error con mi código**, la cuestión es que al ingresar un nuevo registro quiero en automatico se cargue en mi interfaz donde se van a listar los items pero no lo hace, tengo que recargar mi pagina que es lo mismo que si no utilizara *AJAX*. pensaba que al traer los elementos utilizando *AJAX* automaticamente se cargarían pero no. espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Donde ingresas un nuevo registro? En el mismo lugar, o es una seccion aparte?

Comment: No es aparte, otra interfaz y otra consulta utilizo diferentes archivos para llevara  cabo el registro.

Comment: Tú hablas de nuevos datos: *`... la cuestión es que al ingresar un nuevo registro quiero en automatico se cargue en mi interfaz donde se van a listar los items pero no lo hace, tengo que recargar mi pagina que es lo mismo que si no utilizara AJAX. pensaba que al traer los el...`*  pero en el código no muestras donde ingresas esos nuevos datos. Es ahí donde debes actualizar el contenedor (del cliente) para que agregue el nuevo dato que se ingresó. El nuevo dato no puede mostrarse por sí solo, porque cuando creaste/llenaste el contenedor, no existía.

Comment: Es correcto, he agregado que cuando se inserta un nuevo registro se actualice el contenedor y funciona pero no del todo ya que si tengo en una ventana nueva el contenedor este tampoco se actualiza a menos que se recargue la pagina.

Comment: @luis_am92 **ya que si tengo en una ventana nueva el contenedor este tampoco se actualiza a menos que se recargue la pagina.** es decir que creas el registro en una pagina, mientras tienes abierta esta nueva ventana y esperas que al crearlo esta ventana se actualice ?

Comment: @stanchacon es correcto amigo eso quiero, no se si sea posible o si estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: @luis_am92 entonces si quieres hacer eso tienes dos opciones: la primera es que tu función que obtiene la tabla news se refresque cada n minutos, la segunda es usar sockets

Comment: Es correcto he utilizado la primera opción pero real mente no es lo que busco, investigare como funcionan los web sockets, gracias bro.